# Serving up snippets of html and using urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm trying to "modularize" a section of an appengine website where a profile is requested as a small hunk of pre-rendered html

Sending a request to /userInfo?id=4992 sends down some html like:

```
    <div>
    (image of john) John
    Information about this user
    </div>
```

So, from my google appengine code, I need to be able to repeatedly fetch results from this URL when displaying a group of people.

The only way I can do it now is send down a collection of <iframes> like

```
    <iframe src="/userInfo?id=4992"></iframe>
    <iframe src="/userInfo?id=4993"></iframe>
    <iframe src="/userInfo?id=4994"></iframe>
```

The iframes work to request the data.

I tried using [urlfetch.fetch()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html) but it keeps timing out on me.

Am I doing this right?  I thought this would be handy-dandy (url that serves up a snippet of html) but it turns out its looking like a design error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently serializing urlfetch requests, which ends up summing their wait times and may easily push you beyond your latency deadline.  I'm afraid that you'll need to switch to [async urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) requests -- an advanced technique which may suit your architecture better!